# Best way to show to user an element of a table is happening today?

Tags: tables, conventions

I'm making an app where an event list is displayed into a table with sortable columns. Even if there is a Date column, I'd like something to show clearly the items that are planned for today in that list.

I was thinking coloring the element would be wrong. Maybe a icon next to the date or event name?

What is your opinion on this? Is there a known convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the text "Today".  As a "badge" style is no harm either. e.g.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff5g2g.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

The principle is always to match the users mental model.